# Insert Into with sqlCommand and ExecuteNonQuery is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I run the following code on my local mssql server database which uses integrated security, it works fine. When I run it on the remote server where the only difference that I can see is that it uses SQLServer authentication, the insert statement doesn't execute and I get no errors. When I insert or update using SQLDataSource on the server using a listView, the updates work perfectly and i am using the same connection string. I am only having the problem using the SQLCommand with the ExecuteNonQuery. Here is the code:

```
using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
        {
            thisConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.msgs (msg1, msg2) values ('abc', 'abc')", thisConnection);

            int results = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

My Local sqlServer connection string in web.config is

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=MYLAPTOP\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   />
```

My connection string on GoDaddy is :

```
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=username; Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

the insert is just being ignored.

Comment: Is the user have INSERT Permission to the mentioned database?

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I have the connection string in my web config, it would seem that the only difference is declaring the integrated security, copy my connection string and change what you need and see if it works

```
 <add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.1;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=dbUser;Password=dbPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So i think it is just a mistype in your connection string, have a try and let me know

I just noticed you are using sql express in that case you need to use the following

```
<add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.1\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=dbUser;Password=dbPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

as the connection is looking for nons sqlexpress database server, but as it is sqlexpress shove that on the end of the ip and all should be fine

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. When i am connecting to sqlExpress it is on my local computer and I am using integrated security. My Problem is when I connect to GoDaddy's SQLServer which uses SQLServer authentication, that it is not working. I even just tried changing to SQLServer authentication on my local version and it works fine. The problem is clearly on GODaddy

Comment: are you sure you are connecting to the right 'IP' as these are huge hosting farms they dont always have the same 'IP' for the site as the 'DB Server' you should also make that clearer in your post that you are not connecting to a 'sqlexpress' DB as it is off putting also try putting your using statement in a try{}catch{} block as this may show an error that isnt getting thrown further up the stack

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried a try catch block. There was no error. I am sure it is the correct IP because I CAN update the database without a problem as long as I am using an SQLDataSource

Comment: just noticed the fix you posted, thats very strange

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I don't know why this fixed it but it did.
instead of

```
  using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
```

I wrote

```
 string strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection thisConnection =    new SqlConnection(strConnString ))
```

Again - I only had to do this when working against the SQLServer on the Godaddy server but not when I ran it locally using SQLExpress. If anyone could explain, I would be very appreciative.